# Updating WPF XAML Combobox selecteditem from powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, combobox, selecteditem

I'm just simply trying to change the selected item on a combobox drop down from powershell. Whenever I use:

$dg_Servers.Items[0].cbox_Disk.SelectedItem = 88

I receive the error:

"...cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."

Here's my XAML:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DiskC" Visibility="Visible" Width="61"  >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                               <ComboBox
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cbox_DiskC}"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding Path=cbox_DiskD, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.. seems like this should be super easy. System.Windows.Forms makes this a no brainer to accomplish.

EDIT - adding the powershell side:

```
$row= New-Object NewRow -Property @{ServerName = ""; cbox_DiskC = (80..250); cbox_DiskD = (50..250); cbox_DiskE = (1..250); cbox_DiskF = (1..250); cbox_DiskG= (1..250); cbox_Mem=(1..16); cbox_CPU=(1..8); cbox_OSSpec = $Options_OSSpecs; cbox_Template = $Options_Templates; cbox_VLAN = $Options_VLAN ; cbox_Folder =  $Options_Folders }
$itemsource = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[object] -ArgumentList @($row)
$dg_Servers.ItemsSource = $itemsource
```

I read this morning that you have to use an observablecollection in order for the UI to be notified of a change and refresh.. but I'm still not having any luck. I'm only using one thread so maybe that's the issue?

I was trying to change the combobox's drop down selection with another buttons click event.

```
$btn_Validate.Add_Click({$dg_Servers.SelectedItems[0].cbox_DiskC = 88})
```

But as I said, when I click the button on the UI nothing changes and the selection remains the same.

Comment: Try `$dg_Servers.Items[0].cbox_Disk.SelectedValue` instead of `$dg_Servers.Items[0].cbox_Disk.SelectedItem`.

Comment: Same error.. would it be something with -
$dg_Servers.SelectedValue.Cbox_DiskC.Set()

Comment: Without seeing the code on how you define your variables I can't really say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `cbox_DiskD` source property that is bound to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox`:

```
$dg_Servers.Items[0].cbox_DiskD = 88
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the right way to do it but at this point I've spent too much time trying to figure out a better way :)

I had to bind to a different element in my class. Making them different allows me to keep all my items in the dropdown AND select a specific one. Otherwise if I keep them the same, all of my items disappear and it's set to 88.  (NOTE: cbox_DiskC as the itemsource and cbox_DiskC_selected as the selecteditem below)

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DiskC" Visibility="Visible" Width="61" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                               <ComboBox                           
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Path = cbox_DiskC}"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding Path=cbox_DiskC_selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Once I did that, in the add_click I basically $nulled the itemsource, and re-added it which forces my GUI to refresh.

```
$btn_Validate.Add_Click({$row.cbox_DiskC_selected = 88; $dg_Servers.ItemsSource = $null; $dg_Servers.ItemsSource = $itemsource})
```

Later on I'll make a function that does the refresh to clean it up a bit.